# How can I use use JSP 2.1 with Cargo maven plugin and Jetty6x embedded?

Tags: jsp, jetty, cargo

I have a webapp that is using JSP 2.1, Servlets 2.5 and JSTL 1.2 on Java 6. I do my testing using the maven-jetty-plugin 6.1.1rc1 without any problems. From this link: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/JSP+2.0+v+JSP+2.1, I understand that jetty 6 will select JSP 2.1 if on JDK 5+, which is working fine.

Here is the relevant section from my pom.xml of the application war:

```
<!--servlet & javax-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Now I'd like to set up automated integration tests using cargo and jetty6x embedded. The container starts up fine without errors. However, I can't render any JSPs. This is the exception I get, which as far as I can tell is because a JSP-2.0 impl is being used instead of JSP-2.1.

```
(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:547) - Unknown element (deferred-value) in attribute
```

and `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.SetSupport.doEndTag(SetSupport.java:140)`

Here is my cargo config:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
<artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<configuration>
    <container>
        <containerId>jetty6x</containerId>
        <type>embedded</type>
    </container>
    <configuration>
        <deployables>
            <deployable>
                <groupId>groupId</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>
            </deployable>
        </deployables>
    </configuration>
    <wait>${cargo.wait}</wait>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>start-container</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>start</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>stop-container</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>stop</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

The cargo jetty6x container also uses v6.1.1rc1 of jetty, so it must be something to do with the way cargo is using jetty. I know that cargo hard-codes the versions of its container dependencies instead of using the maven dependency mechanism (probably for good reason, jira ->CARGO-571)

So my question is: has anybody else managed to use JSP 2.1 with cargo and jetty 6x embedded? Any suggestions for getting it working?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Is there any particular reason you didn't want to use the jetty7x container? This works with JSP 2.1 straight out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, managed to figure this one out. This post from the cargo mailing list was helpful: 
http://old.nabble.com/Jetty6-version-with-maven-plugin-td16722550.html. It described how you can customize the classpath of the container using cargo, but if you take this approach then you need to specify all the dependencies manually.

I found from the cargo sources that these are the dependencies used by default for jetty6x containers:

```
jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("org.mortbay.jetty", "jsp-api-2.0", "6.1.1rc1"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("org.mortbay.jetty", "servlet-api-2.5", "6.1.1rc1"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("org.mortbay.jetty", "jetty", "6.1.1rc1"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("org.mortbay.jetty", "jetty-util", "6.1.1rc1"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("org.mortbay.jetty", "jetty-naming", "6.1.1rc1"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("org.mortbay.jetty", "jetty-plus", "6.1.1rc1"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("ant", "ant", "1.6.5"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("commons-el", "commons-el", "1.0"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("tomcat", "jasper-compiler", "5.5.15"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("tomcat", "jasper-runtime", "5.5.15"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("tomcat", "jasper-compiler-jdt","5.5.15"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("javax.mail", "mail", "1.4"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("javax.activation", "activation", "1.1"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("geronimo-spec", "geronimo-spec-jta", "1.0.1B-rc4"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("xerces", "xercesImpl","2.6.2"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("xerces", "xmlParserAPIs","2.6.2"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("commons-logging", "commons-logging","1.0.4"));
    jetty6xDependencies.add(new Dependency("log4j", "log4j", "1.2.14"));
```

The problematic ones are the tomcat ones, because they use JSP 2.0. So when setting up the classpath, you need to exclude those, and include JSP-2.1, i.e.

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.1rc1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

So here is the whole configuration:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
<artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<configuration>
    <container>
        <containerId>jjetty6x</containerId>
        <type>embedded</type>
        <implementation>
            org.codehaus.cargo.container.jetty.Jetty6xEmbeddedLocalContainer
        </implementation>
        <timeout>500000</timeout>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>geronimo-spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-spec-jta</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!--replaced these:-->
            <!--<dependency>
                <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasper-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
            </dependency>-->
            <!--with this:-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
                <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-naming</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ant</groupId>
                <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-el</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-el</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </container>
    <configuration>
        <deployables>
            <deployable>
                <groupId>gruopId</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>
            </deployable>
        </deployables>
        <implementation>
            org.codehaus.cargo.container.jetty.Jetty6xEmbeddedStandaloneLocalConfiguration
        </implementation>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>start-container</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>start</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>stop-container</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>stop</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Note that you need to specify all of the dependencies twice - once in the plugin and once as project dependencies. You can get the versions from the first snippet.

Comment: What version of org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-api-2.1 are you using?

Comment: 6.1.1rc1 (taken from the <dependencies> section of the pom.xml)

Comment: Now I'm getting class loading problems with javax/el/ExpressionFactory. What JDK are you using? Also, could you post your entire POM somewhere please?